# C# Repeating a Loop Based on User Input

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# assignment and am pretty much done, except I cannot figure out how to replay the loop based on the user answering "yes" or "no." If they answer yes I want the loop to replay, if they answer no, it will leave a nice goodbye message.

Here's my code (deleted my commenting for simplicity):

```
Random randomNumber = new Random();

        int count = 0;
        int actualNumber = randomNumber.Next(1, 50);
        int userGuess = 0;
        bool correct = false;


        Console.WriteLine("In this program you will be prompted to guess a number between 1 and 50 \n\n" +
            "I'll help by saying if your guess is higher/lower than the actual number\n\n\n\n" +
            "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 50, please enter your guess.\n\n");


        while (!correct)
            {
                count++;

                Console.Write("Guess: ");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (!int.TryParse(input, out userGuess))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("That's not a number between 1 and 50, please try again.");
                    continue;
                }

                if (userGuess < actualNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the number is higher than that, keep guessing!");
                }
                else if (userGuess > actualNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the number is lower than that, keep guessing!.");
                }
                else
                {
                    correct = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} is the right number! It took you         {1} times to guess", userGuess, count);
                }
            }
```

I'm having trouble figuring out if I should use another while statement or an if/else or what and where to use it. I've searched here and found similar questions for different languages, but nothing for C#. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can place your code inside `do-while` loop. And it will ask from user if he or she wants to replay? And if user enters **Yes**, then the game will start again.

```
Random randomNumber = new Random();

do
{  
    int actualNumber = randomNumber.Next(1, 50);
    int count = 0;
    int userGuess = 0;
    bool correct = false;

    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("In this program you will be prompted to guess a number between 1 and 50 \n\n" +
"I'll help by saying if your guess is higher/lower than the actual number\n\n\n\n" +
"I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 50, please enter your guess.\n\n");

    while (!correct)
    {
         // ...your code
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to replay?");
} while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "YES");
```

---

***P.S:*** Initilize `Random` outside the loop as example in above, otherwise it will generate same number.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It works great, but now I'm not running into another issue, I thought this would be a simple thing. I want to clear the screen if the user chooses to play again and NOT show the opening message again, I just want it to prompt "Guess: " I've placed the Console.Clear() command everywhere I can think to put it and it either clears the screen in the wrong spot or it clears it altogether. Can you clarify where I should place my Console.Clear() command? Thanks again!

Comment: @bnr32jason It will not clear part of console automatically. But, yes. You can use `Console.Clear()` inside loop and don't forget to put Console.WriteLine() after this. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but with the Console.Clear() in that position it leaves the opening welcome message "In this program you wil......". Basically I want this welcome message to appear the first time the user runs the program, but immediately after they type "yes" to try again, it clears the screen and only leaves the "Guess:" prompt. I'm really struggling to figure out where to put it. I've went through the debugging process to follow the steps and find where to place it, but nothing gets me the result I want. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @bnr32jason Have you tried my update? It will always add welcome message to the same place.

Comment: I apologize for not explaining myself clearly enough. I only want the welcome message to appear one time. When the user tries again, I don't want the welcome message displayed, only the "Guess:" prompt. So immediately after they type "yes" they have a mostly blank screen in front of them with nothing but the "Guess:" prompt. Hope that makes sense, thanks for the help and sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: @bnr32jason See my update. For getting the expected behaviour you must add flag. Then we will know if the user choose replay or not.

Comment: I wish we could chat about this, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

I tried the latest update you posted (thank you again) but that's actually the first thing I tried. The problem with that order is now it doesn't display the welcome message at all, not even the first time.

Comment: @bnr32jason Hey, wait. My first update was waht you need. Do you want to see welcome message always?

Comment: The first update you made had it display the welcome message every time the player chose to play again. The second update did not display it at all. Perhaps I made a mistake, but I went line by line to compare your example to my code and I'm certain they matched each time.

Comment: @bnr32jason There is not any bult-in function to clear only part of the console. So, it will always clear whole console. And, i put welcome message always after it. And it will always clear all parts, then will add welcome message and then will write **Guess:**. The current update is indeed doing this.

Comment: Ok, I will go back through everything you have told me and see if I can get things worked out. I really appreciate all the time you have spent helping me!

Comment: @bnr32jason Not problem, but tried this update firstly. I think that you have forgot to add ` Console.Clear();` from this update.

Comment: Just send him your homework and let him do it for you! Save a lot of time that way.

Comment: Spiked3: If I wanted to do that, I would have done it in the beginning. Before I asked the first question, I spent a few hours messing around with different loop methods and couldn't figure it out, so I asked. Then I spent an hour just moving the Console.Clear() from place to place, then I asked. I don't think that's completely unreasonable. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: @bnr32jason I am pretty sure that you have not put `Console.Clear()` to the same place with my update.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev I made a completely new project in Visual Studio 13, placed your code in there and then pasted in my loop code. It still shows the welcome message again after I type "yes" to try again.

Comment: @bnr32jason )) OK. But it is clearing firstly whole screen. So, the first welcome message will be removed. And user will not see this process.

My code is doing that:
 *1) Write welcome message to the screen* ;
 *2) Write Guess message to the screen* ;
 *3) After game ends, ask if user wants to replay?* ;
 *4.1) If user chooses  YES, then clear all screen and goto 1 part* ;
 *5.1) If user chooses NO, then quit the application.* ;

What must be changed here?